# Expose schedules and frequency of cron jobs as environment variable on staging vs production.Cron jobs are running on google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

Not able to set the environment variable at deploy time of functions.Since file in which cron jobs clouds functions are written is parsed not executed

I tried writing all environment variables in .env file and then set those environment variable by uploading all environmental variable as secrets

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.